# Как задать ограничения по загрузке изображения

Tags: php, mysql, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать ограничения по загрузке изображения jpeg или gif, размеры картинки не более 300 пикселов по высоте или ширине

```
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

        $target = "img/".basename($image);
        
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO post (title,postDate,preview,textFull,postIMG) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", $_POST['title'], $_POST['postDate'], $_POST['preview'], $_POST['full'],$image);
           if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){

           }
            header("Location: /");
```

Comment: тип файла проверить можно через расширение [FileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.fileinfo.php), разрешение картинки - в зависимости от [установленных модулей](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/refs.utilspec.image.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью функции getimagesize() получаем ширину, высоту и тип изображения. Затем пишем условие на основе этих параметров.

```
$imageFilePath = __DIR__ . '/tmp/image123.jpeg';

[$imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageType] = getimagesize($imageFilePath);

if ($imageWidth <= 300 && $imageHeight <= 300 && in_array($imageType, [IMG_JPEG, IMG_GIF])) {
    // Окей, допускаем изображение к обработке
}
```

Comment: Я что-то сделал не так? :C [Мой код](https://gist.github.com/lordSerega/d8ab7d0196b29e634de3932f04f72616)
Картинки загружаются любого размера :с

Comment: Загружаются в БД и в папку /img? Или что-то одно?

Comment: Ща сам проверю на серваке и отпишусь

Comment: Путь картинки загружается в БД, картинка загружается в папку /img ;(

Comment: Да, ты перепутал содержимое if...else. В if перенеси логику сохранения, а в else перенеси echo 'Файл больше';.